# Two identical tables: Keep them seperate or merge them with extra key column

Tags: sql

Lets assume that we have two statuses tables which are identical. Each table has his own values. They don't share the same.

Now, what is best practice?

- Keep those seperated, or
- Merge them with additional key column

---

**Separate:**

```
Table: offer_statuses
- id
- name  //For example: calculating, sent

Table: project_statuses
- id
- name  //For example: preparation, in progress
```

**Merged:**

```
Table: statuses
- id
- status //For example: offer, project
- name   //For example: calculating, sent, preparation, in progress
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Id keep then separate. A project status is not an offer status.  You gain nothing by combining, and now every foreign key to the combined status table will be two columns instead of one. You can also introduce errors, as your foreign keys will not prevent you from using an offer status where only a project status is valid.

Answer (score 1):

You can go either way.  Normally, there would be a separate reference table for each type of status, because this would allow both:

- foreign key relations from `offers` and `projects` to the appropriate statuses; and
- no accidental mixing of statuses between the two entities.

There are some situations where having all statuses in the same table is useful.  For instance, if the statuses really do overlap, then putting them in the same table makes sense.  Another use-case is internationalization.  If the application needs to be easily translatable, then having all language strings (such as status descriptions) in a single table (or small number thereof) is helpful.

In other words, I would usually go for separate tables.  However, there might be good reasons for combining them.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to keep them separated. It sounds like they're different from the logical point of view. Having the same attributes is an indicator two tables might model the same entity but no proof.

Keeping them different makes it easier to enforce correctness of the data, as you can use foreign key constraints, that point to the right status. If your just have one table it becomes more difficult to ensure, that e.g. offers only use status for offers.